# How to do Prisma runtime model validation?

Tags: orm, prisma, model-validation

In my application, I have validated the input credential at the DTO level by using class-validator. But I need runtime model validation like sequelize ORM.

**In sequelize:**

```
'use strict';
import { DataTypes, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

function User(sequelize: Sequelize) {
  const user = sequelize.define(
    'User',
    {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: new DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isEmail: {
            // args: true,
            msg: 'Invalid email'
          },
          len: {
            args: [1, 100] as readonly [number, number],
            msg: 'Email length should be 1 to 100 characters'
          },
          notNull: {
            // args: true,
            msg: 'Email cannot be empty'
          }
        }
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      tableName: 'users',
      underscored: true,
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
      deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
      paranoid: true
    }
  );

  return user;
}
export default User;
```

Is there any possibility to do model validation in Prisma?

Answer (score 1):

There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3528) for Prisma to support runtime model validation directly at the Schema level. Alternatively, you can leverage the [Client Extensions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/client-extensions) to perform validation. There is an example in this [blog post](https://www.prisma.io/blog/client-extensions-preview-8t3w27xkrxxn?2#example-input-validation) that shows how to perform custom runtime validation.